# Static analysis tool for checking appropriate code commenting

Tags: java, static-analysis, comments

I understand that there are static analysis tool e.g. [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) (there are [bunch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java) of them ) which do the code analysis statically and also can be scheduled as a part of continuous build process. These tool operate on a code part. A commenting is equally important, it would be great if the any discrepancy could be detected and reported to the concerned developer (as a part of build process).

**I was looking for** a capability wherein a tool could also flag the instances where appropriate comments are missing. I am referring to standard javadoc style comments like class, method etc.

Comment: you can also take a look at [qulice.com](http://www.qulice.com), which integrates together Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs, and pre-configures them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to an article I found, **Checkstyle** can do Javadoc validation

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/three-tools-that-make-java-code-review-painless-and-effective/5031836

> ... Unlike PMD, Checkstyle can check for Javadoc commenting; ...